# How to use spaCy’s Rule-Based Matching for sentences extraction

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, feature-extraction, information-retrieval

Good afternoon, I am trying to use  spacy in order to extract french sentences from a list  to another containing a  specific pattern. the negative form  " n'/ne + verb/aux/ + pas + ADV/ADJ/ROOT/NOUN.

I tried to write a small code to test one pattern n'/ne + AUX + ADV but when I  used Spacy, Nothing is done/print. So where I am commiting an error

I do not understand why because I was following a tutorial 
I wanted to check the pattern and if the pattern is present in the sentence , I append it to "sent_extract"

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher  

pattern = [{"POS": "ADV"}, 
           {"POS": "AUX"}, 
           {"LOWER": "pas"}, 
           {"POS": "AVD"},]  # ADV, NOUN, ADJ


pattern2 = [{"POS": "ADV"}, 
           {"POS": "AUX"}, 
           {"LOWER": "pas"}, 
           {"POS": "ROOT"},]


pattern3 = [{"POS": "ADV"}, 
           {"POS": "AUX"}, 
           {"LOWER": "pas"}, 
           {"POS": "ADJ"},]


matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)  
matcher.add("matching_1", None, pattern) 

sentence = ["Voyons ce n'est pas mal ce que vous faites", "Vive la vie.", " Vous n'êtes pas bien.", 
            "Je ne suis pas mauvaise","Jeune gens mangez bien", "Ce n'est pas mauvais"]

sent_extract=[]

for sent in sentence:
    doc=nlp(sent)

    print([t.text for t in doc])

    matches= matcher(doc)

    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = doc[start:end]

        print("found match:", span.text)

        if span.text in sent:
            sent_extract(sent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your patterns carefully, comparing them to the values you see for those features in the tokens in each `doc` you want to match.

`AVD` and `ROOT` aren't possible `POS` values, so those patterns will never match anything.